# Install Mac OS X Lion from newly installed SDD in Mac Book Pro A1260 (2008 model)

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, upgrade

I have an old Mac Book Pro A1260 (2008 early model), and I need to replace the old HDD with SDD. In doing so, I'm thinking about installing Mac OS X Lion.

Can I install Mac OS X Lion directly to my Mac? Do I need to install snow leopard first, and then upgrade to Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

Get a copy of lion from the app store on another Mac and follow this guide

http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive?popular=true

You can clean install from the USB / dvd worked fine here

Comment: I used the above link and it went flawless! I made my own jumpdrive and thats what I use when i want to reformat my mac.